# Threads in a Java Web Application

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I need to create a thread that listens to a filepath for new, modified or removed files. I am using a web application that uses Spring 3, Struts 2 and Hibernate 3. If I run the project, it loads the index.jsp which contains the text "Hello World".

The problem is that when I create a java `Thread()` that listens to the filepath and assign it to index.jsp:

```
<action name="" method="runThread" class="TestThreadBean">
     <result>index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Then "Hello World" text does not ever appear because the Thread doesn't ever stop (Which is right, it's not supposed to stop). I need this Thread to be running in the background and not interfere with the rest of the web application. I don't want to create a separate web application just for this Thread though. Also, I don't want a `new` Thread instance to be created each time a `new` Session instance is created, there should be just one Thread instance no matter how many Session instances there are active.

Comment: You actually don't need to do anything special to run threads in Tomcat. You can just create them as usual, with `new Thread` or an `Executor`. This is not compliant with the J2EE spec, but the fact is that it works. Doing it in a spec-compliant way is not straightforward, particularly in a container that implements the servlet spec but not the rest of J2EE.

Comment: What exactly you meant by "Client side"?

Comment: You need a scheduler mechanism for this, Try using `Quartz` and a `SimpleTrigger`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, people will suggest not to start your own thread in a container managed application, like a web application or an enterprise (EJB) application.

This is because in a container environment all the resources including threads should be managed by container. But IMHO if you know the implications, and the life cycle of our own thread and its resources, like wrapping this thread with a transaction etc, then we can create a thread by using the standard way (`new Thread()`), but it is just my opinion.

I would suggest you to go through the 'Container managed threads' once before you make a decision. You can refer [commonJ](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/commonj/commonj.html#wp1057962) once to get a handle to Container's thread pool, but as this is not a standard or not mentioned in the container specifications, It may not work for all the containers. This will work for:

- [Weblogic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/config_wls/self_tuned.html)
- [Websphere](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/asyncbns/concepts/casb_workmgr.html)
- [Tomcat, Jboss and may be for others](http://commonj.myfoo.de/)

Comment: @ThreaT There is one in the commonJ link provided.

Comment: @ThreaT why should a server-side thread be aware of the client?

Comment: So maybe you need to schedule an activity, and a Work is not what you're looking for.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14066/discussion-between-carlo-and-threat)

Comment: @ThreaT Not deleting this answer because you substantially changed the question *after* the answer was posted.  You can request from the poster of the answer to change the answer, but generally, radically changing the question *after* there are answers is a very, very bad idea.