# How to run task in the background in web application?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a submit button in a JSP. This button calls 2 functions: `function A(…)` and `function B(…)`. The latter sends emails to many users, maybe 1000 users or 2000. When I click on the submit button, the page keeps loading until the emails have been sent to all of the users. This takes too much time.

Is there any way to make the page load just until `function A` has finished and then run `function B` in the background? or does anyone have any other suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: @subash that cannot be solved with ajax calls.

Comment: Use a [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/threads.html) to send the email.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Threads in a Java Web Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540458/threads-in-a-java-web-application)

Comment: `ExecutoService` might help

Comment: @RC. and other people suggesting use of threads: you must be aware about the implicances of firing new threads that aren't managed by the container in the application server. In other words, don't play with fire at least that you know what you're doing.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you need to maintain coherence with your container state. For this specific problem, I would have the webapp write somewhere the "emails data" and a specialized daemon handling email sending (easier to handle restarts etc)

Comment: Can give some suggestions if your question is clear. But what would happen if user submit A twice ? will you send same mail again ?

Answer (score 0):

Make it work by AJAX calling two servlets or JSPs.   When you click the button it does an AJAX call to servlet_A, and when you get the response back from there and put the output in a DIV or something, then make an AJAX call to servlet_B and let it take however long it will.

Contrary to what was said in a comment above, AJAX would be good for this because it runs asynchronously.  You send off the request and whenever the response comes back, you do something with it or don't.